# Why do the flames in my ventless fireplace go out when I turn on the blower?

Tags: gas, fireplace

I have a ventless gas fireplace. It starts fine but when I turn on the blower motor on Manual the flames go out after a few minutes (but not the pilot light). If I put the blower motor on auto the flames will go out after a few minutes but then eventually come back on (again the pilot light does not go out). This obviously doesn't sound normal to me

Comment: It sounds like the flame behaves the same regardless of blower mode. This is probably because the flame is thermostatically controlled. Is that the case? If so, what you describe is what I'd expect to happen.

Comment: If I don't have the blower on the flames stay lit, I'm thinking the blower motor is actually blowing the flames out and an adjustment is needed

Comment: I'd think you'd be smelling gas in that case.